# DTD allows missing tag

Tags: xml, dtd

This is my DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT my-root (element1,element2+)> 

    <!ELEMENT element1 (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT element2 (element3,(element4?|element5+))>

    <!ELEMENT element3 (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT element5 (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT element4 (element6*)>

    <!ELEMENT element6 (element5*,element7*)>

    <!ELEMENT element7 (#PCDATA)>
```

And this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE my-root SYSTEM "my-root.dtd">

<my-root>

    <element1>a-location</element1>

    <element2>
        <element3>a-value</element3>
        <element4>
            <element6>
                <element5>test</element5>
                <element5>test2</element5>
                <element7>test3</element7>
            </element6>
        </element4>
    </element2>

    <element2>
        <element3>test4</element3>
        <element5>test5</element5>
        <element5>test6</element5>
    </element2>

    <element2>
        <element3>test7</element3>
    </element2>
</my-root>
```

My question is why is it valid even though there is no element5 tag in the last element2.

Or rather, how can I tell the DTD that at least 1 element5 is required where there is no element4 present inside the element2 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `element4` required so it's exactly one `element4` or one or more `element5`...

```
<!ELEMENT element2 (element3,(element4|element5+))>
```

Comment: Aaargh, you are right. The ? is zero or 1 isn't it, not exactly 1. Well spotted Daniel. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can just use comma (,) instead of pipe (|) sign:

```
<!ELEMENT element2 (element3,(element4?,element5+))>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Changing the PIPE to a comma still validates the XML with the missing tag.